# form_for with a select helper using 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I have two models offer and country they don't have any relationship, but in my new offer form, I want a select tag for select the country of the offer.

Here is my new action:

```
def new
    @countries = Country.all
    @offer = Offer.new
end
```

and this is my view

```
<%= form_for(@offer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select @countries %> #I know this is wrong.
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to select the country of an offer, that implies there should be a relationship in the models.

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offers
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for :offer do |form| %>
  <%= form.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If this is not what you're after please refine your question.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this work, but I don't understand why I have to make this relationship between the models.

Comment: It's a pretty basic concept within the realm of relational data. If you have two objects and one needs to select an instance of the other then they are related. As an example: a `human` can have many `pets`, to describe this and keep track of a humans pets each instance of `pet` will have a `human_id`, the pet now 'belongs to' a human. Rails works closely with this concept.